# jQuery UI: Draggable clone and change clone

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've got button `<div class='button' data-tag='h1'>Drag to insert h1 tag</div>`

When you drag it I want button to stay where it was, helper to be `<h1>Example</h1>` and where you drop it, you'll drop `h1` tag without any draggable or jQuery UI styles.

So:

You drag something from button > you've got `h1` tag in air, you drop unstyled `h1` tag.

I've got this:

```
        var html = "<h1>Example</h1>";
        $('.button').draggable({
            connectToSortable: '.drop-area',
            containment: 'document',
            helper: function(){ return $(html); }
        });
```

And it makes helper to be `h1` tag, but when I drop it, dropped item is button, not `h1` tag.

In other words I've got a lot of buttons with various html tags or structures. Those buttons displays only name of tag and when you drag it, you see real tag to be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `drop` function you can access the original dragged item using `ui.draggable`, so you can clone it and append it into the droppable element.

Quick ref:

> draggable - Type: jQuery - A jQuery object representing the draggable
>   element.
>
> helper - Type: jQuery - A jQuery object representing the helper that
>   is being dragged.

Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Code:

```
$(function () {
    var html = "<h1>Example</h1>";
        $('.button').draggable({
            connectToSortable: '.drop-area',
            containment: 'document',
            helper: function(){ return $(html); }
        });
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Cp6Rr/